# How to calculate sum with multiple joins involved

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
with a as (
    select
        1 as id,
        1 as value
),

b as (
    select
        1 as id,
        1 as a_id,
        1 as value
    union all select 2, 1, 2
    union all select 3, 1, 3
    union all select 4, 1, 3
),

d as (
    select
        1 as id,
        1 as b_id,
        1 as value
    union all select 2, 1, 2
    union all select 3, 1, 3
)

select
    a.id,
    b.id,
    b.value as b_value,
    d.id
from a
left join b on a.id = b.a_id
left join d on b.id = d.b_id;
```

[image]

Is it possible to calculate `sum(b.value)` as 9 instead of 11?

I've been trying to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440065/13338593), but with no success.

`sum(b.value) * (count(distinct b.id)::decimal / count(*))` will give 7.3 instead of 9.

Comment: sum(b.column_1) * (count(distinct b.id)::decimal / count(*))  mean (8 *3)/4 = 6 .. not 4.8 ..

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: On what basis you wanted to ignore two rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to identify duplicate rows. Then the aggregation is simple. For example:

```
with a as (
    select
        1 as id,
        1 as value
),
b as (
    select
        1 as id,
        1 as a_id,
        1 as value
    union all select 2, 1, 2
    union all select 3, 1, 3
    union all select 4, 1, 3
),
d as (
    select
        1 as id,
        1 as b_id,
        1 as value
    union all select 2, 1, 2
    union all select 3, 1, 3
)
select sum(col1)
from (
  select b.id, max(b.value) as col1
  from a
  left join b on a.id = b.a_id
  left join d on b.id = d.b_id
  group by b.id
) x
```

Result:

```
9
```

See running example in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mq8qPL2S6kJBk623zd7tLJ/1).

Comment: what if i have duplicate values for column_1 at table b? i will lose those

Comment: If that's a different use case, can you add the new example to the question?

Comment: Ah... so table `b` has no PK, since you have two rows with exact same values.

Comment: sorry, this is a mistake. b  dose have PK. updated again